# How do I get the old behavior of "CTRL+BACK_ARROW" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I recently upgraded my version of Eclipse to 3.7, and now I can no longer use `Ctrl-Back Arrow` to move to the beginning of a line.  It now will only go to the beginning of the text on the line, but no further.  How can I restore the old behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just press the home button to get to the beginning of a line? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Edit: Based on the comment you can change shortcuts through the following process.

Choose the `Eclipse > Preferences` menu command to open the Eclipse workbench Preferences. Select the `General > Editor > Keys` page. From here you can change the key bindings of shortcuts (Home is probably the one you want, as Previous Word is what is currently bound to Ctrl+Left)

Comment: Yes, but it's frustrating to have to relearn how to navigate with the keyboard.  Besides, the home key toggles between moving to the start of the line and the end of the whitespace that starts the line.  Very annoying.

Comment: @Mike This was close, but it's impossible to fix the key bindings to act the same as it does in every other application on windows. Probably one of the most frustrating things about using eclipse for me.